# Magento 2.3: Forward to another URL without redirecting

Tags: module, magento2.3, url, redirect-url, router

**I'm writing a module that will accept any Magento URL with** /discount/COUPON_CODE appended to the end, set the code in a cookie for later use, and then forward to the URL minus the discount part.

So, for example, https://store.url/page/path/discount/COUPON_CODE would eventually load the page that would have been found at https://store.url/page/path.

The tricky part is that I can't do a 300 redirect (that would have been easy.) I want to actually forward to the appropriate controller/action internally so that the discount code URL remains intact. I'm having a really hard time figuring out how to do this.

Right now, I have a plugin for FrontControllerInterface with a beforeDispatch method that examines the URL, and if a discount code is found, sets it in a cookie. At the end of this method, I was hoping to strip /discount/COUPON_CODE from the URL and then continue dispatching using the modified URL, but I'm not sure this is the right approach (if it is, I can't figure out how.)

**Does anyone have an idea** of how I might accomplish this? I can see that there are ways I can dispatch a specific controller or action using a custom router, but **I can't figure out how to match an arbitrary URL to the correct controller and action once I've modified it.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a solution that works for me. In the beforeDispatch() method of my FrontControllerInterface plugin, I have the following block of code:

```
$requestPath = $this->request->getPathInfo();

// If a coupon code was included in the URL, fix the URL
// after extracting it so that we can continue to route normally
if (preg_match("#/discount/([^/]+?)/*$#", $requestPath, $matches)) {

    $coupon = $matches[1];
    $realPath = str_replace($matches[0], '', $requestPath);

    if (!$realPath) {
        $realPath = '/';
    }

    $this->request->setPathInfo($realPath);
}
```

This does exactly what I need. Hope it can also help someone else in the future.

EDIT: The plugin I was writing can be found here: https://github.com/crankycyclops/DiscountCodeUrl It's a free and open source means to automatically apply coupon codes via the URL. Hope someone finds it useful :)

Answer (score -1):

For this your requirement, you need to use [**`Custom routers`**](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/routing.html#custom-routers**) instead of plugin on  `FrontControllerInterface`etc.

**Custom router** has the ability to handle the custom URL as per as business logic.

**Custom router** internally hit the Magento Standard router Url `www.example.com/<front-name>/<controller-name>/<action-name>` .At Magento ,if **you want to  output/render from an Action** then your URL must be hit `<front-name>/<controller-name>/<action-name>` directly or indirectly

A good example is the Magento Cms module' router  [`Magento\Cms\Controller\Router`](https://github.com/devamitbera/magento2/blob/2.3-develop/app/code/Magento/Cms/Controller/Router.php).

```
        $page = $this->_pageFactory->create();
        $pageId = $page->checkIdentifier($identifier, $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId());
        if (!$pageId) {
            return null;
        }
        $request->setModuleName('cms')->setControllerName('page')->setActionName('view')->setParam('page_id', $pageId);
        $request->setAlias(\Magento\Framework\Url::REWRITE_REQUEST_PATH_ALIAS, $identifier);
        return $this->actionFactory->create(\Magento\Framework\App\Action\Forward::class);
```

You need when a user is hit cms page identifier then it's internally hit  magento `www.example/cms/page/view` with params `page_id/$pageId`

You need to build the same logic for this requirement.

### Declare Custom router at di.xml

First create `di.xml` at `app/code/{VendorName}/{ModuleName}/etc/frontend`.
And Defined Custom router here.

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" ?>
> <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
>     <!--Add Custom route-->
>     <type name="Magento\Framework\App\RouterList">
>         <arguments>
>             <argument name="routerList" xsi:type="array">
>                 <item name="crankycyclops" xsi:type="array">
>                     <item name="class" xsi:type="string">VendorName\ModuleName\Controller\Router</item>
>                     <item name="disable" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
>                     <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">31</item>
>                 </item>
>             </argument>
>         </arguments>       
>     </type>
>  </config>
> ```

### Custom router Class

After that create Custom router class *`VendorName\ModuleName\Controller\Router`* where you build the logic for `/page/path/discount/COUPON_CODE`  routing.

Assume that **Url** is `www.example.com/myurlone/myurltwo/discount/COUPON_CODE`.

Here: `www.example.com/myurlone/myurltwo/discount/COUPON_CODE` hit

= `www.example.com/routing/index/index/discount_code/COUPON_CODE`

**Code**

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace VendorName\ModuleName\Controller;

use Magento\Framework\App\ActionFactory;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Forward;

class Router implements \Magento\Framework\App\RouterInterface {

    /**
     * @var ActionFactory
     */
    private $actionFactory;

    public function __construct(
        ActionFactory $actionFactory
    ) {

        $this->actionFactory = $actionFactory;
    }

    public function match(\Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request) {


        $identifier = trim($request->getPathInfo(), '/');
        $condition = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject(['identifier' => $identifier, 'continue' => true]);
        $identifier = $condition->getIdentifier(); 

        if (strpos($identifier, 'myurlone/myurltwo/discount') === false) {
            return null;
        }

        /**
         * Split myurlone/myurltwo/discount/COUPON_CODE by /
         */
        $urlParts = explode('/', $identifier);

        /**
         * if $urlParts count is more then 4 or less then custom route return null means not match  
         */
        if(count($urlParts) > 4 && count($urlParts) <3 ){
            return null;
        }

        if($urlParts[0] !== 'myurlone' ||  $urlParts[1] !== 'myurltwo' 
                ||   $urlParts[2] !== 'discount'){
             return null;
        }

        $discountCode = $urlParts[3]; // $urlParts[3]   = COUPON_CODE

        /**
         * here assume that  COUPON_CODE is NOT match 
         *  Changes the logic as per your requirement
         */

        if($discountCode  === 'NOT MATCH'){
            return null;
        }

        /**
         * if match 
         */

        $request->setModuleName('routing');
        $request->setControllerName('index');
        $request->setActionName('index');
        $request->setParams([
            'discount_code' => $discountCode
        ]);

        return $this->actionFactory->create(Forward::class, ['request' => $request]);
    }

}
```

Comment: How will this work for any arbitrary URL? I want to transform http://my.store/any_possible_url/discount/CODE to a request for http://my.store/any_possible_url. any_possible_url could have any number of parts and could contain any number of different strings. You're only matching one specific URL.

Comment: Figured out how to do what I needed using my plugin. See my answer above.

Comment: @Crankycyclops, your solution is ok but I don't think it appropriate

Comment: Fair enough. If you can come up with a better solution that covers the criteria mentioned in the original question, I'll consider changing my approach.

Comment: @AmitBera can you help me on this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/296960/how-to-fetch-post-method-xml-data-in-magento2